# div contents via .load() in javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load up the contents of an page to a div using JavaScript. I have a file called test.html that I want to load:

```
  $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $("#cont #Dynamic").load('/public/' + id + '.html');
   });
```

...

```
<a href="#" id="test" name="modal">link</a>
<div id="cont">
    <div id="Dynamic"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `name` is not valid attribute for `<a>`, use a class or id selector .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point of the two id selectors. As long as id is valid and the request returns a content this will work.

```
$("#Dynamic").load('/public/' + id + '.html');
```

Comment: im jumping into this website after its built. the 2 id selectors is precaution... single didnt work either...

Comment: blackhawks got a win last night lol they're first goal was sick btw =)

Comment: it does work. i realize that im using a smarty template and my directories are a little difficult. I'm an idiot. it works. i didnt need help lol.

Comment: deeer... i have to pay more attention. check paths!